# Is there a difference between "git pull --rebase" and "git fetch && git rebase --autostash FETCH_HEAD"?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase, git-pull, git-fetch

Title says it all. Is there a difference between:

`git pull --rebase --autostash`

and

`git fetch && git rebase --autostash FETCH_HEAD`?

And while we're at it, between:

`git pull`

and

`git fetch && git merge`?

Thanks!

Comment: The `pull` command adds `--fork-point` when doing rebase. It changes the merge message slightly when doing merge. In very old versions of Git (that predate `--autostash`), there are some additional minor differences.

Answer (score 1):

The below mentioned command

```
git pull --autostash
```

will stash your local changes and then perform `pull`.

`pull` is a combination of `fetch` and `merge`. 
`fetch` doesn't merge the remote changes to local branches.
So,

```
git pull
```

is similar to

```
git fetch && git merge
```

Hopefully, this might answer your query.

Comment: "*`git pull --rebase` is similar to `git fetch && git merge`*" Certainly no — it's similar to `git fetch && git rebase`.